# Java Android Mesclando projetos

Tags: java, android

As vezes eu preciso utilizar um projeto em outro como por exemplo um framework UI em minha aplicação ou coisa do tipo e a maioria deles estão disponíveis em repositórios como github etc, geralmente faço o download e extraio os arquivos para pasta do meu projeto mas logo o eclipse começa a alertar vários erros geralmente por dois motivos

1. O importe da classe `R` referente ao pacote esta errado ou seja ele
   geralmente referencia ao pacote original do framework não ao do meu
   projeto (Coisa Obvia rsrs)
2. A classe `R` não identifica os Resources e eles muitas vezes ficam
   inacessíveis

Acredito que provavelmente estou incorporando de forma errada um projeto no outro gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer isso de forma simples, toda vez que decido usar algum Framework UI é uma gerra eu preciso corrigir todos esses erros na mão.

Comment: Poderia responder as seguintes perguntas? Está colocando os fontes da library direto no seu projeto (módulo)? Qual IDE esta usando (Eclipse, Android Studio ou outra)? Qual sistema de build (ant, gradle ou maven)? Poderia também incluir o link de uma dessas libraries?

Comment: Estou usando o Eclipse meu sistema de build é o padrão do eclipse, estou colocando os fontes direto no projeto, as classes e os arquivos xml de layout, um dos projetos que estou incluindo é este https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Como não uso o Eclipse para desenvolvimento Android, não consigo gerar uma resposta satisfatória. Mas deixo minha contribuição: Sempre que fizer checkout de um repositório de uma library, tente criar um projeto Eclipse (módulo) separado para ele (tendo sua própria pasta `res` e seu próprio `AndroidManifest`), com isso você já evita problemas com referências a classe `R`, pois cada projeto tem uma. De uma olhada em http://www.simpligility.com/2010/07/multi-module-android-project-in-eclipse/. Mais...

Comment: O Eclipse usa o Ant para fazer Build e gerar o APK. Acho que é possível usar o Maven para gerenciar suas dependências, digo isso porque muitas libraries (e.g : https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/GlassActionBar) submetem módulos ao Maven Repository, usando Maven ou Gradle é muito fácil incluir em seu código (https://gist.github.com/wakim/42ee30ceb958a3f80110), assim evitando o problema de uso.

Comment: Quando for iniciar um novo projeto Android, de uma olhada no Android Studio, pode ser opinião pessoal mas nunca mais volto para o Eclipse depois que mudei, não tem comparação.

Comment: @Wakim na verdade eu também prefiro o Android Studio rs eu optei em usar o eclipse porque essas library estavam com o build do eclipse. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o projeto como módulo da sua aplicação principal (a que vai fazer o uso dos **resources**) e marque para ser compilada juntamente com o projeto.

Isso vai permitir você acessar os arquivos de classes do projeto incluído.

Para permitir o acesso aos resources é necessário também, adicionar a **pasta do projeto incluído** como módulo na solução do projeto principal.

Ficando então 2 pastas na sua IDE:

```
Minha Aplicacao:
Projeto Principal/
Projeto Incluido/
```

[image: Exemplo de como vai ficar, no caso estou usando 2 libs]

Certifique-se de que o projeto incluido esteja marcado como **Library**.

Todas essas opções você encontra na propriedades do seu projeto/solução.